# trying to yield return with remove

Tags: python

I need to generate an iterator for a deck of cards. I MUST NOT use another import but random.

I don't understand why if I removes cards from the deck after yield I get after a few tries
"ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"

Is it because I am changing the deck inside the for? how can I solve it without import deep copy? tnx

```
import random

NUMS_IN_DECK = 13

def take_card():
    type_cards = "diamond", "heart", "spade", "club"
    deck = [(i + 1 ,t)  for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK) for t in type_cards]
    
    for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK * len(type_cards)):
        card_to_return = random.sample(deck, 1)
        yield card_to_return
        deck.remove(card_to_return)

card_iter = take_card()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(card_iter))
```

Comment: You don't need to `import copy`, for starters, you can just use `my_list.copy()`, a `deepcopy` is not necessary here, and even if it were, you could probably just implement it for your list (say, you cared because it contained *other* lists, then you can just do `[sub_list.copy() for sub_list in my_list]`

Comment: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) returns a list of elements.  `[tuple(x)] != tuple(x)`.  I would use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead.

Comment: But you just need to do `deck = random.sample(deck, NUMS_IN_DECK * len(type_cards))` and just yield from that list, or `random.shuffle(deck)` then `for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK * len(type_cards)): yield deck.pop()` or something like that

Comment: @0x5453 good point, but it's actually `[some_tuple] != some_tuple`

Comment: Also consider `random.shuffle` to randomize the order of the deck, and then `while deck: yield deck.pop()` to emit cards until it is exhausted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, good point.  Edited my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is that `random.sample` returns a `list`, and that `list` is never in `deck`, but you are over-complicating this. Just do:

```
import random

NUMS_IN_DECK = 13

def take_card():
    type_cards = "diamond", "heart", "spade", "club"
    deck = [(i + 1 ,t)  for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK) for t in type_cards]
    random.shuffle(deck)
    for card in deck:
        yield card
```

Answer (score 1):

The yield statement returns an array, which is then searched in card_to_return.
In your case if the first card selected is (12, 'diamond'), it is saved as a list [(12, 'diamond')].

This array is searched in the deck. Since there are only elements and no list inside the deck list, it returns the "not found" error.

The correct way would be to search only for (12, 'diamond') in the deck which can be done by selecting the element at index 0 in card_to_return list using `deck.remove(card_to_return[0])`

The correct implementation would be as follows:

```
import random

NUMS_IN_DECK = 13

def take_card():
    type_cards = "diamond", "heart", "spade", "club"
    deck = [(i + 1 ,t)  for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK) for t in type_cards]
    
    for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK * len(type_cards)):
        card_to_return = random.sample(deck, 1)
        yield card_to_return
        deck.remove(card_to_return[0])

card_iter = take_card()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(card_iter))
```

Comment: probably they didn't mean to `yield card_to_return` but `yield card_to_return[0]`

Comment: `yield card_to_return[0]` still yields a list. could do card_to_return = random.sample(deck, 1)[0] instead. but it works either way.

Comment: No, it doesn't yield a `list`. What you've shown is equivalent anyway.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you..? I onle did a minor change.

```
import random
NUMS_IN_DECK = 13
def take_card():
    type_cards = "diamond", "heart", "spade", "club"
    deck = [(i + 1, t) for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK) for t in type_cards]
    for i in range(NUMS_IN_DECK * len(type_cards)):
        card_to_return = random.choice(deck)
        yield card_to_return
        deck.remove(card_to_return)

card_iter = take_card()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(card_iter))
```